# Materialize modal doesn't work until page is refreshed in Angular2

Tags: jquery, angular, modal-dialog, materialize

I have a modal that opens upon a button click.
It works as expected if I reload the page, but if I navigate from the main page to the NewMatch component, the button click does nothing.

```
export class NewMatchComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      //TODO fix bug where navigating from main to newmatch and then clicking the modal submit sometimes works and sometimes doesn't (depending on whether you've navigated away from the page before??)
      $('.modal').modal();
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
...
}
```

Here are my package dependenices in package.json:

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "angular-froala-wysiwyg": "^2.7.2-1",
    "angular2-materialize": "^15.1.10",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "materialize-css": "^0.100.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "@types/youtube": "0.0.29",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ngx-youtube-player": "0.0.41",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  }
...
```

And here is the html of the modal and button serving as modal trigger (adapted from the [Materialize css modal page](http://materializecss.com/modals.html):

```
....
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>Annotate your submission?</h4>
        <p>You can either go ahead and annotate your own submission, or it will be added to the annotation queue, to be annotated at some later time.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button (click)="annotateCurrentVideo()" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn">Annotate</button>
        <button (click)="addToQueueAndReturnToMain()" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn">Add to Queue</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn modal-trigger waves-effect waves-light" data-target="modal1">Submit
      <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
    </button>
...
```

I have github repo with a branch that reproduces the error here:

```
git clone https://github.com/Atticus29/dataJitsu.git
cd dataJitsu
git checkout modalSO
rm package-lock.json
npm install
ng serve
```

From the main pack, click "New Match", then click the "Submit" button. Nothing should happen. If you reload that page, the "Submit" button should open a modal.

I'm using Google Chrome Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: If I understood it correctly the code in your constructor is used to programmatically open your modal when the document is ready. Is this really what you are trying to achieve? Also I'd highly recommend not to use the `document.ready` function in angular and rather put that code into one of its life cycle hooks that usually do a similar job in a much cleaner way. Your code for opening the modal through the button looks correct but I think it may be broken through your constructor call

Comment: @BenediktSchmidt I think that I originally tried it in the ngOnInit call, but it didn't work for some reason.  I'll confirm this tomorrow. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @BenediktSchmidt, moving $('.modal').modal(); into ngOnInit(){} worked! Didn't realize that I could do that. Thanks!